# Unable to run static-compiled hello-world executable from AWS lambda function

Tags: c, python-3.x, linux, aws-lambda, executable

First time posting a question here, open to feedback.

I am trying to get an executable running in AWS lambda, however I am getting the error "cannot execute binary file" which is quite vague (more outputs below).
I am hoping to identify what could be wrong, and why.
As a disclaimer I am not very good at c or python.

Currently my process has been to write a hello world program in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Create an AWS instance which matches the Python 3.8 lambda runtime (Amazon Linux 2)
(Tried on Amazon Linux 1 with the same results)
Install compiler tools

```
sudo yum install gcc
sudo yum install glibc-static
```

Compile the program to a static executable

```
gcc -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ hello.c -o testings
```

Also tried with less flags with similar results.

```
gcc -static hello.c -o testings
```

Have also tried as a 32 bit binary using -m32 flag. Tried this as looking at the cpu information for the lambda runtime showed a 32 bit processor.

Verify it has compiled with static dependencies

```
file testings
```

with the results

```
testings: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=7167aa934c751be053864ee555be8f6a46e4d62e, not stripped
```

and

```
ldd testings
```

with the results

```
    not a dynamic executable
```

I've copied it to my local machine, changed the file permissions to allow execution, zipped it and uploaded it to lambda.

Which contains two files.
testings (the compiled c program)
lambda_function.py which looks like

```
import json
from subprocess import run, call

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    call(["ls -ll"], shell=True)
    print("using run")
    out = run(["./testings"], shell=True)
    print("printing result")
    print(out.returncode)
    print("printing output")
    print(out.stdout)
    print("printing error")
    print(out.stderr)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('hello')
    }
```

The output of running this function is:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"hello\""
}

Request ID:
"fb640125-6698-4777-841a-47228d4da930"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: fb640125-6698-4777-841a-47228d4da930 Version: $LATEST
total 1092
-rwxrwxrwx 1 slicer 497     426 Jan 13 07:03 lambda_function.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 slicer 497 1111526 Jan 13 06:32 testings
using run
/bin/sh: ./testings: cannot execute binary file
printing result
126
printing output
None
printing error
None
END RequestId: fb640125-6698-4777-841a-47228d4da930
REPORT RequestId: fb640125-6698-4777-841a-47228d4da930  Duration: 24.81 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 58 MB  Init Duration: 113.42 ms
```

I can run the executable on the AWS instance where it was compiled and on my local machine (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS).

I have read quite a few similar questions (running executable in lambda) and am aware this is not a new question, however I haven't managed to find a solution that works for me ( I suspect I am misunderstanding something fundamental, as this is a very new domain for me.)

Additional Information:

using readelf to look at the binaries headers:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - GNU
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x400950
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          699480 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         6
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         33
  Section header string table index: 32
```

Comment: You seem to use the GCC (c compiler), but advise it to link against the static C++  standard library? Then, I don't really get the point in your 'Verify it has compiled with static dependencies', while the quoted output states : `dynamically linked (uses shared libs)` - doesn't this output just proof the opposite? Could you give the output of `ldd testing` to verify that it has been statically linked indeed?

Comment: Could you try to do a simple `gcc -static hello.c -o testings` and verify static linkage by `ldd testings` ?

Comment: @Michael Beer Sorry for the mistake, I will update the question above. I should have used the command file testings over file testing. The output of the testings file does say its statically linked:
testings: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=7167aa934c751be053864ee555be8f6a46e4d62e, not stripped

I'll retry the process without the additional -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ tags when compiling (Followed an online guide which mentioned they were a sort of catch all) Will update with results.